# Android: How to get all the displays of a device

Tags: android, device

Is it possible to enumerate all the displays supported by an Android device? The APIs currently support getting the default display, but don't appear to support getting any other displays.

Comment: I did not find any official API for multiple device displays, even if it looks like it will support it in the future.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I think you are right, for the current state of Android. Perhaps you should write up your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any official API for multiple device displays, even if it looks like it will support it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, I think you're confused about what `getDefaultDisplay` does, it gets the display of the current device, not the global Android default, which does not exist! For information about screen sizes/densities look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Or perhaps you're confused about my question? Maybe I should reword it, but I didn't say anything about a global default. There is at least one Android device with a dual display, but they use their own API extensions. Other Android devices support video out, but there don't appear to be standard APIs to get at all the displays of a device.